# with ggplot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I need little help. I try to do plot with ggplot package. When I want to make plot, depends of more than 1 factor (for example here: plot changes when średnia1 and odchylenie1 change):

```
alpha = 0.05
N = 100
sample_l = 10
srednia1 = seq(-7, 7, by = 1)
odchylenie1 = seq(1, 10, by = 1)
srednia2 = 2
odchylenie2 = 2
prob = 0.7

params = expand.grid(sample_l, srednia1, odchylenie1, srednia2, odchylenie2, prob)
str(params)
names(params) = c("dlugość", "średnia1", "odchylenie1", "średnia2", "odchyelnie2", "prawdopodobienstwo")


set.seed(100)
now <- Sys.time()
powers <- sapply(1:nrow(params), function(p){
  l <- params[p, 1]
  par_1 <- c(params[p, 2],params[p, 3])
  par_2 <- c(params[p, 4], params[p, 5])
  p <- params[p,6]
  p_sim <-sapply(rep(l, N), function(x){
    my_sample <- rmix(l,"norm", par_1, "norm", par_2, p)
    shapiro.test(my_sample)$p.value
  })
  mean(p_sim < alpha)
})
Sys.time() - now

power_df <- bind_cols(params, power = powers)

power_df %>% ggplot(aes(x = średnia1, 
                        y = power,
                        col = factor(odchylenie1))) +
  geom_line()
```

it work perfect, but now, when I want to make plot only depends of 1 factor - **prob** something goes wrong. I have error : Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (150): x, y. Here is a code:

```
alpha = 0.05
N = 100
sample_l = 10
srednia1 = 2
odchylenie1 = 2
srednia2 = 1
odchylenie2 = 1
prob = seq(0.1,0.9,by=0.1)

set.seed(100)
now <- Sys.time()
powers <- sapply(1:nrow(params), function(p){
  l <- params[p, 1]
  par_1 <- c(params[p, 2],params[p, 3])
  par_2 <- c(params[p, 4], params[p, 5])
  p <- params[p,6]
  p_sim <-sapply(rep(l, N), function(x){
    my_sample <- rmix(l,"norm", par_1, "norm", par_2, p)
    shapiro.test(my_sample)$p.value
  })
  mean(p_sim < alpha)
})
Sys.time() - now


power_df <- bind_cols(params, power = powers)

power_df %>% ggplot(aes(x = prob, y = power)) + geom_line()
```

PLEASE HELP ME :(

Comment: Is `prob` part of your `power_df` dataframe?

Comment: in this moment i noticed, i don't copy code lines, which create me expand.gird.. and my x axis has "old" data (150) and y "new" data (only 9 value od prob). Thank U! <3